# Error app:processDebugResources

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Buen dia, amigos tengo el siguiente error al tratar de integrar el SDK de Appodeal.

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

Esta el la configuracion de Gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.thestream"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 4
        versionName "2.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}



repositories {

    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'




implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-rtmp:r2.5.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6'





implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' //for Inmobi
implementation name: 'adcolony-sdk-3.2.1', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mmedia-6.4.0', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_alphab', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_appwall', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_appwallext', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_common', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_interstitial', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_mvdownloads', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_mvjscommon', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_mvnative', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_nativeex', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_offerwall', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_playercommon', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_reward', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_videocommon', ext: 'aar'
implementation name: 'mobvista_videofeeds', ext: 'aar'

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Y esta la del Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:name="com.app.thestream.activities.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.thestream.activities.ActivitySplash"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.thestream.activities.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.thestream.activities.ActivityDetailChannel"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.thestream.activities.ActivityDetailCategory"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.thestream.activities.ActivitySearch"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.thestream.activities.ActivityStreamPlayer"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.thestream.activities.ActivityRtmpPlayer"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.thestream.activities.FullScreenVideoPlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.thestream.activities.ActivityYoutubePlayer"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />




    <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.InterstitialActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.VideoActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.LoaderActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.VideoPlayerActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.appodeal.ads.AppodealPackageAddedReceiver" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.TestActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />



    <activity android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

    <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
    <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinConfirmationActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.RewardedMraidActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.VASTActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.VPAIDActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

    <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.networks.vpaid.VPAIDActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

    <activity android:name="com.amazon.device.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="com.my.target.ads.MyTargetActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>

    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.ads.list3d.List3DActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.activities.OverlayActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.activities.FullScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <service android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.common.metaData.PeriodicMetaDataService" />
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <service android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.common.metaData.InfoEventService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.common.metaData.BootCompleteListener" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <service android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaService" android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" android:process=":Metrica">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="com.yandex.metrica.IMetricaService" />
            <data android:scheme="metrica" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="metrica:api:level" android:value="58" />
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaEventHandler"
        android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity"
        android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity"
        android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads2.adunit.AdUnitActivity"
        android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads2.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity"
        android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />

    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyOverlay"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyBrowser"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.vungle.publisher.VideoFullScreenAdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.vungle.publisher.MraidFullScreenAdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.vungle.publisher.FlexViewAdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>

    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.flurry.android.FlurryFullscreenTakeoverActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.flurry.android.FlurryShareActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.flurry.android.FlurryTileAdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.flurry.android.FlurryBrowserActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <activity android:name="com.mobvista.msdk.offerwall.view.MVOfferWallActivity"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.mobvista.msdk.offerwall.view.MVOfferWallRewardVideoActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.mobvista.msdk.reward.player.MVRewardVideoActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.mobvista.msdk.videofeeds.vfplayer.VideoFeedsActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.mobvista.msdk.out.LoadingActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.mobvista.msdk.interstitial.view.MVInterstitialActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.mobvista.msdk.shell.MVActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.TJAdUnitActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.mraid.view.ActionHandler" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.mraid.view.Browser" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.TJContentActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />

    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.ControllerActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.InterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.OpenUrlActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.adcolony.sdk.AdColonyInterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
    <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <activity android:name="com.adcolony.sdk.AdColonyAdViewActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>

    <activity android:name="com.inmobi.rendering.InMobiAdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|smallestScreenSize|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:resizeableActivity="false" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
    <receiver android:name="com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.uid.ImIdShareBroadCastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.inmobi.share.id"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data android:name="presage_key" android:value="000000"/>
    <service android:name="io.presage.PresageService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:process=":remote">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="io.presage.PresageService.PIVOT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <activity android:name="io.presage.activities.PresageActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="io.presage.intent.action.LAUNCH_WEBVIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="io.presage.receiver.NetworkChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="io.presage.receiver.NetworkChangeReceiver.ONDESTROY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="io.presage.receiver.AlarmReceiver" />
    <provider
        android:name="io.presage.provider.PresageProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.PresageProvider"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

    <!--optional, remove if not using Millennial Media-->
    <provider
        android:name="com.millennialmedia.internal.utils.MediaContentProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.MediaContentProvider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false" />





















</application>
```